# WordPress functions not working within html codc

Tags: php, html, wordpress

[This is the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deq52.jpg)

This is what appears in the browser:

> template directory
>
> This is going to be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser. While
>   this is going to be parsed.
>
> This will also be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser.
>   Otherwise this will show.
>
> This is a php within html.

So the PHP works within html but does not work when a WordPress function is called.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LaPizzaria</title>
    <?php

     ?>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>template directory</h1>
      <p>This is going to be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser.</p>
      <?php echo 'While this is going to be parsed.'; ?><br>
      <p>This will also be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser.</p>

      <?php if ($expression == true): ?>
  This will show if the expression is true.
      <?php else: ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
      <?php endif; ?>
      <p<?php if ($highlight): ?> class="highlight"<?php endif;?>>This is a php within html.</p>
      <header class="site-header">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="<?php get_template_directory_uri() ?>">
          <h1><?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?></h1>
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you use this code ? in a template file ?

Comment: this is the header.php file on my locathost